# UIDocumentMenuViewController ignored allowedUTIs and shows all file types

Tags: ios, ios8, dropbox

I'm adding a new iOS8 `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to my app, and have set the `allowedUTIs` to only allow PDF files:

```
NSArray* docTypes = @[ (NSString*)kUTTypePDF ];
UIDocumentMenuViewController* picker = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:docTypes inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
[picker release];
```

However, when selecting a document from Dropbox it is still listing all files regardless of type. Is this expected behaviour? Is there another way to filter which file types the user can select? Or do I just need to show a "Sorry, we don't handle files of that type!" message when the user selects the wrong kind of file?

Comment: Finally, Dropbox have admitted that this is a bug in their specific document picker, not an issue with iOS itself: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201454819-How-do-I-restrict-document-types-using-the-iOS-8-Document-Picker-?locale=en-us

Comment: This was fixed with an update a couple months ago.